# How can I get the time execution in Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, console

I have a python script. I want to know the time execution, but we can't use library. I need to get the time from the anaconda Prompt

Someone can help me?

[This my python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPwR8.png)

I need to get the time of execution in the Anaconda Prompt. I don't if exists a command or something to give me that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in the question. I edit the question. If you can help me please

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking how you can measure the execution time of the call that you have shown?

Comment: I think he is asking how to time the run of his script. In linux it would be using `time` I think but I have the same question , how to time it in windows

Comment: I am still trying to make it work but I read that using `powershell -Command "Measure-Command {python your_script.py}"` might work